# View Model data passing as null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 6
I created a model and then a view model (to add) which looks like this

```
public class ContactViewModel
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please write your message.")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I created another View model to be able to use multiple view models in the index form this view model looks like this:

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    public  ContactViewModel ContactViewModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Category { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the Index view I have something like this:

```
@model project.Models.ViewModels.MenuViewModel
<form method="post" asp-action="ContactMe" asp-controller="Contact" id="contact-form">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Name</label>
 <input name="ContactViewModel.Name" asp-for="ContactViewModel.Name" type="text" 
 class="form-control" id="name">
 <span asp-validation-for="ContactViewModel.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Email</label>
 <input name="ContactViewModel.Email" asp-for="ContactViewModel.Email" type="text" 
 class="form-control" id="Email">
 <span asp-validation-for="ContactViewModel.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Message</label>
 <input name="ContactViewModel.Message" asp-for="ContactViewModel.Message" type="text" 
 class="form-control" id="Message">
 <span asp-validation-for="ContactViewModel.Message" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>

<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-5 py-2" value="Send">

</form>
```

In the controller I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ContactMe(MenuViewModel menu)
{
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

       //add to db
}
```

When I submit the form, the `ContactViewModel` is null (please see screenshot) instead of the values entered in the frontend - any idea how to fix this please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to apply the `[FromForm]` attribute to your action parameter, like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ContactMe([FromForm]MenuViewModel menu)
{
   //...
```

And use browser Network tool to check if the posted data of the request look like below.

[image]